# How to perform unit testing with databases in PHP Unit 8.0 or greater

Tags: database, phpunit, dbunit

I am running a PHP project and I am using PHPUnit for unit testing. Up until recently I used PHPUnit 4.0 with DBUnit as an extension for database testing. I changed now to PHPUnit 8.0 but could not find a suitable database testing extension to test my backend functions with a test database connected. Also the documentation of PHPUnit does not contain any hint for database testing.

What module/extension replaces DBUnit for PHPUnit 8.0 or higher?

Thanks

Christian

Comment: Hello Christian, I didn't use DBUnit extensively, do you know at which PHPUnit between 4.0 and 8.0 it got dropped? - /E: just seeing: phpunit/phpunit: ^7.0 - https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/dbunit